# Instagram photo feed Angular 5

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I would like to display some pictures of my business instagram feed in my webapp built in Angular 5.
I've created a first "working" (but limited) version using [InstaFeed](http://instafeedjs.com/) but this rely on https://www.instagram.com/developer/ which is being deprecated.

We now have to use [Facebook Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/) but i'm struggling to integrate it with Angular.
Here is my full requirement:

- Display some photo from my business instagram account
- Passing a hashtag to retrieve only some of the photo
- Passing a max number to retrieve X photo (and not all the one matching the hashtag)

My main problem is how to get an access token to authenticate my GET, my users aren't login into my app. Is there something like a public access token ? Or do I need to use my own access token (from my personal account) and if so, does that represent any security issue?

I would also want to get some photo from my facebook business page, and I guess the access token would work more or less the same way.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use your own acess token on booth, on facebook and on instagram.

To access instagram check here for more info: http://instagram.pixelunion.net/

To access facebook look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks for pixelunion link, are you using that way in a live product? Still concern about exposing my own personal access token and also about the expire time

Comment: I think the facebook token don`t expire since you have an active acount. For facebook you have here a nice guide : https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/